# Заполнение массива рандомными числами в интервале [5,100]

Tags: java

У меня в принципе работает код, но почему то вывод не совсем корректный. Программа выдает 5 рандомно сгенерированных чисел из массива и затем еще одну не совсем, мне новичку, понятную срочку(что то по-типу *[I@458ad742*). Ниже часть моего кода ответственная за генерацию массива.

```
public class RandomIntArray {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int n=0;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(createRandom(n)));

}
public static int[] createRandom(int n) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите длинну массива");
    int array_length = scn.nextInt();
    int[] array;
    array = new int[array_length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) + 5);
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    return array;
}

public static String toString(int[] a) {
    java.util.Arrays.toString(a);
    return String.valueOf(a);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Результат выполнения ``java.util.Arrays.toString(a)`` нужно чему-то присвоить. Сейчас это просто бесполезная конструкция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком виде у вас код не скомпилируется.

```
 System.out.println(toString(createRandom(n)));
```

Тут вы не указываете на чем вы вызываете метод тоСтринг. Если вы хотите вывести на экран массив, то необходимо воспользоваться статических методом класса Arrays. Замените эту строку на такую:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(createRandom(n)));
```

Все дело в том, чтобы вывести какой-либо объект на экран, у этого объекта должен быть переопределен метод toString(). Если данный метод не переопределен, то выведется toString() класса Object. Потому что все объекты в Java наследуются от класса Object. Поэтому вы и получаете на экран что-то типа **[I@2077d4de**

upd Тогда вам нужно поправить свой метод toString:

```
public class RandomIntArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n=0;
        System.out.println(toString(createRandom(n)));
    }
    public static int[] createRandom(int n) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите длинну массива");
        int array_length = scn.nextInt();
        int[] array;
        array = new int[array_length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) + 5);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        return array;
    }
    public static String toString(int[] a) {

        return Arrays.toString(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: Все дело в том, что у меня на это прописан отдельный класс, который должен выполнять данную функцию, но видимо я в нем допустил ошибку, сейчас добавлю его к примеру кода.

Comment: @dagsincomming тогда вам нужно поправить метод. Я добавил в ответ